# Yii How to retrieve data from DB and display in view

Tags: php, yii

I trying to retrieve data from DB...But I face some problem

Following is my coding:

**In Controller :**

```
public function actionFinalCheck()
{

    $gametitle=GamesDevelopersApp::model()->find('develper_id=1',array('gametitle'));
    $this->render('finalcheck',array('gametitle'=>$gametitle));
}
```

**In View(PHP):**

```
<?php print_r($gametitle); ?>
```

What I need is `"select gametitle from db where developer_id=1"` but in **Yii** I not sure how to do

OR any better way to retrieve data from DB and display in view ? Thanks

Comment: can you try using `print_r` instead of echo and see what happens?

Comment: @roullie tried result is "Array()" <-this word

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by the ways listed below:

**Active Record**

You need to have a model and by model you can fetch data like below:

```
$object=GamesDevelopersApp::model()->findByAttributes(array("develper_id"=>1));
echo $object->gametitle; // prints gametitle
```

**Query Builder**

```
$row=Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('gametitle')->from('db')->where('id=1')->queryRow();
echo $row['gametitle']; //prints gametitle
```

**DAO (Data Access Objects)**

```
$sql="select gametitle from db where developer_id=1";
$command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryRow();
echo $command['gametitle']; //prints gametitle
```

Comment: and id developer_id is the primary key, use findByPK($developer_id)

Comment: Nice One Ali. Banging My Head Since Last 1 Hour And, I Got Here. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the parameter :developer_id but are not using it in the condition. 
Try passing it a CDBCriteria object like below:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->compare('id', 1); // Check that the column gametitle is equal to 1
$gametitle=GamesDevelopersApp::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

See findAll method for ACtiveRecord http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAll-detail  for details

Comment: thanks but if i have to assign id is 1? Cause normally is 

`select gametitle from db where id='1';`

Comment: `include(CdbCriteria.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory `

Comment: Sorry I had an incorrect case on the CDbCriteria name. It's corrected now.
Also, if your key is id you will need to use that for the field name. Yii determines which table you are querying from the model

Answer (score 0):

I use this it worked fine for me !

**In controller**

```
public function actionFinalCheck()
{

    $developer_id = 'developer_id=1';
    $gametitle=GamesDevelopersApp::model()->find($developer_id);

    $this->render('finalcheck',array('gametitle'=>$gametitle));
}
```

**In View(PHP):**

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode($gametitle->gametitle); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getQuotes()
    {    
       $sql="select * from db";
        $command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
        foreach($command as $commands)
        echo $commands['gametitle']; 
    }
```

**In view:**

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode($model->gametitle)?>
```