# yii how to get simple all records from table

Tags: database, activerecord, yii, model

The question is, how to get all records from a table very simple. As I understand from the documentation, which is not really filled with examples, I should use the ActiveRecords technology.

With that there is a method 'findAll' to get all records from a database table. For e.g. I have a User-Table with id, firstname, lastname, email.

Therefore I could address the records in the User-Table in my controller with:

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;
use app\models\Users;

class UsersController extends \yii\webController

public function actionList()
{
$users = Users::find()->all();
return $thiss->render('list', array('users'->$users));
}
}
```

When I look at the result, this confuses me! I get:

> Array([0] => app\model\Users Object ([_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ([id] => 1 [firstname]=> Testfirstname........[_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private].......[_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private]...

It is a mix of arrays and objects. Is there something wrong? Or how can I extract my values like a simple statement "Select * from users"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26601560/4229270

Comment: I have seen this link, but Iam looking for the right procedure without conditions. The easiest one of all select statements. This link does not show how to handle queries without conditions.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-datareader.html

Comment: This is a different approach from Yii, to get values of a database table. I see that I can also use including classical SQL-statements. But this is not the ActiveRecords technique. I guess there must be a solution to do that with the ActiveRecords approach, or am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry man, Im not Yii programmer, I just tried to get some help to you, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-databases.html

Comment: Thank you for your help Sinto! Iam struggeling since two days, because I cannot find one complete example to do an easy get all records request and populate it in a view with yii. I guess using ActiveRecords should be the right way, but Iam still not successful. As you can see in my post, the result is very confusing. And Iam not able to extract the values of that result.

Comment: I think its a object on array '0', can you able to convert that to array. Take 0th element from array & convert that to array. You can seen id, first name on your output. ($URvar[0]->toArray() or (array)$URvar[0]) Im not sure, try on.

Comment: The problems is, that there are several objects in that array, which holds my data. This leads to the questions, why are there several objects, which is the right object, and how can I easily get the data of the right object? Because there is only one datarecord in the table, there is only one Array. If there are more datarecords, this will really get complex.

Comment: `Array([0] => app\model\Users Object ([_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ([id] => 1 [firstname]=> Testfirstname` 
Try getting 0th value, as your out its an Object convert it to array & try to reach `Array ([id] => 1 [firstname]=> Testfirstname`

Comment: Therefore it must be an easy procedure implemented, otherwise the framework makes more work than it can bring relaxation. But I cannot find the easy way. Maybe Iam also completely wrong with the ActiveRecords technology in Yii?!